# How to skip an if statement if a certain command is written

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

Im making a text-based adventure "game" for practice, (And I realize this is probably the correct way to do it) and I want the user to be able to input 'Command' to see what commands he can currently use - and if they already know the commands, I want them to be able to just input the command itself (Which in this case is 1, 2 or 3). However, the problem I'm having is that if the user inputs 'Command', they won't be able to use them (1,2 or 3) afterwards. I know I could use another scanner, but I am trying to avoid that here.

```
    out.print("\nWhat do you want to do? *Type 'Commands' to look through your options.*\n");

    String playerInput = userInput.nextLine();
    if (playerInput.equals("Commands")){
        out.println("\nCommands\n"
                + "(1) - Inspect\n"
                + "(2) - Explore\n"
                + "(3) - Inventory\n");
    }

    if (playerInput.equals("1")) {
        out.print("You find a box under your bed. \nDo you want to open it?  (Y/N)\n");

        String playerAnswer = userAnswer.nextLine();
        if (playerAnswer.equals("Y")) {
            out.println("Inside the box you find a photograph");
    }
        // Another if statement with option 2 here
}
```

Comment: Do you have a loop around your snippet? How else would you read the second input after the user entered 'Commands'?

Comment: I am very new to programming and wasn't even sure if a loop would be appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop until some exit condition is met. Note that every time `userInput.nextLine()` is called, it will wait for the user to input a new line of text and assign that to `playerInput` before continuing.

```
String playerInput = "";
out.print("\nWhat do you want to do? *Type 'Commands' to look through your options.*\n");
while(! playerInput.equals("Exit")){
    playerInput = userInput.nextLine();
    if (playerInput.equals("Commands")){
        out.println("\nCommands\n"
                + "(1) - Inspect\n"
                + "(2) - Explore\n"
                + "(3) - Inventory\n"
                + "Exit - Quits the game\n");
    }

    if (playerInput.equals("1")) {
        out.print("You find a box under your bed. \nDo you want to open it?  (Y/N)\n");

        String playerAnswer = userAnswer.nextLine();
        if (playerAnswer.equals("Y")) {
            out.println("Inside the box you find a photograph");
    }

    //More if statements...
}
```

Comment: But can I use the same scanner several times?

Comment: In the way I've used it (repeatedly calling nextLine() to get a new line of input), sure.